# SQL SERVER Update and Insert to different table that has duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, Table A and B. I want to update the RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE column of Table A with the value from Table B. However, for category_alert_ctr 55 and 82. There are 2 possible RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE from Table B.

I want to insert a new row in Table A to accommodate both of those RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE (CRM1b and crm1c). Then update the value with the correct value from Table B.

[image: Table A and B]

So the expected result will be :

```
55 | crm1b1 | CRM1     | CRM1b

83 | crm1b1 | CRM1     | crm1c

82 | Area1  | BuildApp | OFC01

84 | Area1  | BuildApp | OFC02
```

Do you have any idea to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you wan to `UPDATE` or `INSERT`?

Comment: @D-Shih I want to update table A with the value from table B.

Comment: is there a limit to how many other values there could be? Is 2 the maximum, 3, 4, 70?

Comment: @Larnu there is no limitation in table B. so if table B has 3 records, I want to insert 2 new records to accommodate it.

Comment: So, if you only want 2 out of the 3 what is the logic behind the one that isn't used? If you have 17, what is the logic behind the 15 that aren't used? How do we determine which should be displaying in your 2 columns when we have an infinite number of possible options?

Comment: @Larnu If I have 17 duplicates, the first record in Table A needs to be updated with the first record in Table B. And after that, I need to insert 16 records in Table A to accommodate the remaining 16 records fro Table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement to insert such rows from Table B that are not in Table A, and update those that are in Table A.

To check, click [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36df2311e8510406dad5fe78bdbc4466).

```
with
  a as (
    select
      *,
      row_number() over(
        partition by category_alert_ctr order by (select 0)
      ) rn
    from @A
  ),
  b as (
    select
      *,
      row_number() over(
        partition by RAM_CATEGORY_CODE, RAM_GROUP
        order by RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE
      ) rn,
      row_number() over(
        order by RAM_CATEGORY_CODE, RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE
      ) cac_offset
    from @B
  ),
  m as (
    select
      a.category_alert_ctr,
      iif(b.rn = 1 and a.category_alert_ctr is not null,
          a.category_alert_ctr,
          max(a.category_alert_ctr) over() + b.cac_offset) new_cac,
      b.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE, b.RAM_GROUP, b.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE, b.rn
    from b
    left join a
      on b.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE = a.ram_category_code and
         b.RAM_GROUP = a.RAM_GROUP and b.rn = a.rn
  )
merge a
using m
  on a.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE = m.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE and
     a.RAM_GROUP = m.RAM_GROUP and a.rn = m.rn
when matched then
  update set
    a.category_alert_ctr = m.new_cac,
    a.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE = m.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE
when not matched then
  insert(category_alert_ctr, ram_category_code,
         RAM_GROUP, RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE)
  values(m.new_cac, m.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE,
         m.RAM_GROUP, m.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

to handle multiple matches, use row_number() to generate a unique numbering for matching

```
UPDATE     A
SET        RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE = B.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE 
FROM       (
               SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RAM_CATEGORY_CODE, RAM_GROUP 
                                                     ORDER BY RAM_CATEGORY_CODE)
               FROM   TABLEA
           ) A
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RAM_CATEGORY_CODE, RAM_GROUP 
                                                     ORDER BY RAM_CATEGORY_CODE)
               FROM   TABLEB
           ) B
ON         A.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE = B.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE
AND        A.RAM_GROUP         = B.RAM_GROUP
AND        A.RN                = B.RN
```

Answer (score 0):

If necessary to update the `category_alert_ctr` column.

To check, click [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=289834b5c7304fde130b779617f90955).

```
declare @A table(
    category_alert_ctr int,
    ram_category_code varchar(30),
    RAM_GROUP varchar(30),
    RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE varchar(30)
);

insert @A values
    (25, 'HLTHLIC_FF', 'HEALTHLIC', null),
    (28, 'M16', 'QBL', null),
    (55, 'crm1b1', 'CRM1', null),
    (55, 'crm1b1', 'CRM1', null),
    (82, 'Area1', 'BuildApp', null),
    (82, 'Area1', 'BuildApp', null);

declare @B table(
    RAM_CATEGORY_CODE varchar(30),
    RAM_GROUP varchar(30),
    RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE varchar(30)
);

insert @B values
    ('HLTHLIC_FF', 'HEALTHLIC', 'HLTHLC_RST'),
    ('M16', 'QBL', 'EPA'),
    ('crm1b1', 'CRM1', 'CRM1b'),
    ('crm1b1', 'CRM1', 'crm1c'),
    ('Area1', 'BuildApp', 'OFC01'),
    ('Area1', 'BuildApp', 'OFC02');

with
    a as (
        select
            *,
            iif(
                row_number() over(
                    partition by category_alert_ctr order by (select 0)
                ) = 1,
                category_alert_ctr,
                max(category_alert_ctr) over() +
                    row_number() over(order by category_alert_ctr) -
                    dense_rank() over(order by category_alert_ctr)
            ) new_category_alert_ctr,
            row_number() over(
                partition by category_alert_ctr order by (select 0)
            ) rn
        from @A
    ),
    b as (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over(
                partition by RAM_CATEGORY_CODE, RAM_GROUP
                order by RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE
            ) rn
        from @B
    )
update a
    set a.category_alert_ctr = a2.new_category_alert_ctr,
        a.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE = b.RAM_PARENT_CATEGORY_CODE
from a
join a a2
    on a.category_alert_ctr = a2.category_alert_ctr and a.rn = a2.rn
join b
    on a.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE = a.RAM_CATEGORY_CODE and
       a.RAM_GROUP = b.RAM_GROUP and a.rn = b.rn
;

select * from @A;
```